# Safari on iOS doesn't show ellipsis on text overflow

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

My code:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello <span>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span> World!</p>
```

**Chrome on Desktop**

[image]

**Safari on iOS**

[image]

Somehow, the "..." isn't displayed in Safari.

If I select the number on my IPhone, it certainly overflows, so IMO the "..." should be shown.

[image]

Does anyone know why this could be happening? I searched online, but couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) the `text-overflow` property only applies to block-level elements. But `<span>` is an inline-level element.

Comment: @tromgy that's why I added `display: inline-block;`. This works on Chrome, so I think it's the right way? Is this an chrome-only-thing?

Comment: Yes, you're right. For this purpose `inline-block` should work... and it does  have just tested your hello example both on iPadOS and iOS with Safari and in both cases it shows **abcd...**

Comment: @tromgy okay, I found the bug. It's actually a safari bug. It stops working when the text in the span reaches a couple of thousand characters.

Comment: It's probably not a bug rather that by design (not saying its right). I want to ask why do you wan't ellipsis on a paragraph that has 1000s of characters? It's most common use case is a short introduction text, one example could be a "teaser card".

Answer (score 0):

Whit the property `preline`:
Sequences of white space are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

```css
text {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```